# ¿Cómo crear un menú lateral desplegable con Materializecss?

Tags: materialize

Quiero hacer algo como esto:

[image: imagen]

Pero que el menú no se sobreponga por encima de todo y que los hijos de desplieguen cuando se le de click encima del padre.

Éste es mi código:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!-- START LEFT SIDEBAR NAV-->
<aside id="left-sidebar-nav">
  <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed leftside-navigation">
    <li class="bold"><a href="" class="waves-effect waves-cyan"><i
                                        class="mdi-action-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="no-padding">
      <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
        <li class="bold"><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-cyan"><i
                                                class="mdi-action-view-carousel"></i> Layouts</a>

          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Full Screen</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Horizontal Menu</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="bold"><a href="" class="waves-effect waves-cyan"><i
                                        class="mdi-communication-email"></i> Mailbox <span
                                        class="new badge">4</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="bold"><a href="app-calendar.html" class="waves-effect waves-cyan"><i
                                        class="mdi-editor-insert-invitation"></i> Calender</a>
    </li>
    <li class="no-padding">
      <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
        <li class="bold"><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-cyan"><i
                                                class="mdi-action-invert-colors"></i> CSS</a>

          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Typography</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Icons</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Animations</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Shadow</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Media</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="l ">Sass</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="bold "><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-cyan active "><i
                                                class="mdi-image-palette "></i> Elements</a>

          <div class="collapsible-body ">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=" ">Alerts</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Buttons</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Badges</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Breadcrumbs</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Collections</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Collapsibles</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Tabs</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Navbar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Pagination</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Preloader</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Toasts</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Tooltip</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Waves</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="bold "><a href=" " class="waves-effect waves-cyan "><i
                                                class="mdi-device-now-widgets "></i> Widgets</a>
        </li>
        <li class="bold "><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-cyan "><i
                                                class="mdi-editor-border-all "></i> Tables</a>

          <div class="collapsible-body ">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=" ">Basic Tables</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Data Tables</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">jsGrid</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Editable Table</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">floatThead</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="bold "><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-cyan "><i
                                                class="mdi-social-pages "></i> Pages</a>

          <div class="collapsible-body ">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=" ">Contact Page</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">ToDos</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Blog Type 1</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Blog Type 2</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">404</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">500</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Blank</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="bold "><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-cyan "><i
                                                class="mdi-action-shopping-cart "></i> eCommers</a>

          <div class="collapsible-body ">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=" ">Products Page</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Pricing Table</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Invoice</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="bold "><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-cyan "><i
                                                class="mdi-image-image "></i> Medias</a>

          <div class="collapsible-body ">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=" ">Gallery Page</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Image Hover Effects</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="bold "><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-cyan "><i
                                                class="mdi-action-account-circle "></i> User</a>

          <div class="collapsible-body ">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=" ">User Profile</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Login</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Register</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Forgot Password</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Lock Screen</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="bold "><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-cyan "><i
                                                class="mdi-editor-insert-chart "></i> Charts</a>

          <div class="collapsible-body ">
            <ul>
              <li><a href=" ">Chart JS</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Chartist</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Morris Charts</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">xCharts</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Flot Charts</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=" ">Sparkline Charts</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="# " data-activates="slide-out " class="sidebar-collapse btn-floating btn-medium waves-effect waves-light hide-on-large-only cyan "><i class="mdi-navigation-menu "></i></a>
</aside>
<!-- END LEFT SIDEBAR NAV-->
```

Comment: Hola Roger David, esta pregunta es demasiado amplia y podría solucionarse de mil maneras diferentes. Debes ser más concreto: ¿cómo es el menú que quieres crear? (una imagen vale más que mil palabras), ¿qué has intentado hasta el momento? (incluye tu código) ¿Con qué problemas/errores te estás encontrando? (explica qué es lo que te falla).